# Java permutation algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, permutation

So I have this code now, and in input I have in ascending order my name's letters "ahimrsu". I need to show up the right number for "mariush" from all combinations which should to be 2170. For now it only show ahimrsu, ahimrus, ahimsru, ahimsur, ahimurs, ahimusr, ahirmus, ahirmsu.... etc How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<!--Script Function Start Here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
        function perms(data) {
    if (!(data instanceof Array)) {
        throw new TypeError("input data must be an Array");
    }

    data = data.slice();  // make a copy
    var permutations = [],
        stack = [];

    function doPerm() {
        if (data.length == 0) {
            permutations.push(stack.slice());
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var x = data.splice(i, 1);
            stack.push(x);
            doPerm();
            stack.pop();
            data.splice(i, 0, x);
        }
    }

    doPerm();
    return permutations;
}

var input = "ahimrsu".split('');
var result = perms(input);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i].join('');
}
console.log(result);
</script>
<!--Header start here-->
</head>
<body>
<!--Script Result-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(result);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I recomend you read about variations and permutations in general.

Comment: The formula is `factorial(str.length)`.

Comment: Why you tagged java?

Comment: Now the second question that has the same amount of "quality". You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, before you ask the next question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Sorting / Selecting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493579/java-sorting-selecting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is of mathematics nature - combinations and permutations. You are actually asking the number of possible permutation for string length 7.
The formula is factorial(numOfchar).

`In this case 7! = 7x6x5x4x3x2x1 = 5040.`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "ABCDEFH";

    System.out.println("Number of permutations for " + str + " is : " + factorial(str.length()));
}


public static int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    int result = factorial(n-1)*n;
    return result;  
}
```

**Program Output:**

`Number of permutations for ABCDEFH is : 5040`

Since you tagged `Java`, this is one way you can get the it done with Java.

Comment: I tagged JAVA because I need to do it in JAVA thank you for your answer